# Timeouts on async socket communication with SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, timeout, socketasynceventargs

I'm using SocketAsyncEventArgs to communicate with hundreds of equipments (most of them through GPRS). Sometimes, some of them stop responding and it seems I have no way of timing out the operation, as the documentation states that the timeout options (i.e [SocketOptionName.SendTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) doesn't work on asynchronous communication.

I'm looking for a way of check for timeouts when doing Send/Receive/ConnectAsync. It should not block the thread (so, calling someMonitor.WaitOne(SomeTimeoutValue) won't do) and I don't want to create a timer instance per operation (as the number of equipments will surely increase).

Any tips on this?

Comment: Which transport protocol are you using? Maybe there is a wrapper class like [UDPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) or TCP classes that already solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did it (altough I didn't like the solution):

the idea is to have one timer that, when fired, checks all the pending operations for timeouts. 
I created an interface that my async client implements:

```
public interface ITimeoutable {
    event Action<ITimeoutable, Operation> Begin;
    event Action<ITimeoutable, Operation> End;
    void DoTimeout(Operation operation);
}
```

where Operation is an enum, defined as:

```
public enum Operation {
    Connect,
    Send,
    Receive,
    Disconnect
}
```

so, the client raises a `Begin` event when starting an async operation and raises the `End` event when finishes it. On the other side, I've created a TimeoutManager, which has a collection of async clients and a dictionary with the operations and the instant they were started. When a new client is created, it is registered into the `TimeoutManager`, which subscribes to the events. The `TimeoutManager` uses a `System.Threading.Timer` to check which operations timed out. If it has a timeout, then it calls the `DoTimeout` method (from the `ITimeoutable` interface).

It is a fairly complex code, and I don't like it. But it works.